# SQL Group By and Limit issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried searching for this but I cannot seem to find an answer to this. Lets say I have two tables, one called threads and one called comments. My goal is to select threads based on some condition (but limit them to a total of 3), and for each thread, join it with top 3 comments (top 5 being determined by date, or some other column).

I had a difficult time figuring out how to just limit the number of comments, since MySQL seems to have issues with LIMIT being in a subquery in some cases.

Shortened schema:

```
thread: id, owner, creation_time
comment: id, thread_id, creation_time, display_time
```

Here is how I query now:

```
SELECT t.*, c1.*
FROM thread as t
JOIN comment c1 ON c1.thread_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN comment c2 ON c2.thread_id = c1.thread_id AND c2.display_time < c1.display_time
GROUP BY t.id, c1.id
HAVING COUNT(c2.id) < 3 and t.owner='test@test.com'
ORDER BY t.creation_time, c1.display_time
```

This is based off of http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,128132,128134#msg-128134. However, I need to limit the total number of groups being returned, and adding LIMITs seems to only result in syntax errors. Essentially, I want to paginate through threads, but for each thread, have up to x number of comments linked to it

Does anyone know how to do this or have any resources that can shed some light on this? For context, I am using MySQL 5.5.

Sample data for thread:

```
  | id  |     owner      |    creation_time    |
  |  1  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  2  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-08 06:45   |
  |  3  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-09 07:53   |
  |  4  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-10 03:21   |
  |  5  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-11 11:27   |
  |  6  |  test@test.com |  2014-06-12 13:05   |
```

Sample data for comment:

```
  | id  |  thread_id  |  creation_time      |  display_time       |
  |  1  |      1      |  2014-06-07 03:45   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  2  |      1      |  2014-06-08 06:45   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  3  |      1      |  2014-06-09 07:53   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  4  |      1      |  2014-06-10 03:21   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  5  |      1      |  2014-06-11 11:27   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  7  |      2      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  8  |      2      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  9  |      2      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  10 |      2      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  11 |      3      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  12 |      4      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  13 |      4      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  14 |      4      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
  |  15 |      4      |  2014-06-12 13:05   |  2014-06-07 03:45   |
```

Sample results:

```
  | thread_id | comment_id | 
  |    1      |     1      |  
  |    1      |     2      |  
  |    1      |     3      |  
  |    2      |     7      |  
  |    2      |     8      |  
  |    2      |     9      |  
  |    3      |     11     |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Edited to add sample data and results. Please let me know if that does not clear it up. I basically wanted to group threads with comments, but only top x comment *And* only top x threads.

Comment: Looks like a `JOIN` between two sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```
SELECT t.id, t.creation_time, c.id, c.creation_time
FROM (SELECT id, creation_time  
      FROM thread
      ORDER BY creation_time DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c ON c.thread_id = t.id
WHERE 3 >= (SELECT COUNT(1) 
            FROM comment c2 
            WHERE c.thread_id = c2.thread_id 
            AND c.creation_time <= c2.creation_time
           )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae9d2b/10/0

Comment: This seems to have worked for me! Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to do this in SQLAlchemy :)