# Join between sub-queries in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In relation to the answer I accepted for this post, [SQL Group By and Limit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973184/sql-group-by-and-limit-issue/27974016#27974016), I need to figure out how to create that query using SQLAlchemy. For reference, the query I need to run is:

```
SELECT t.id, t.creation_time, c.id, c.creation_time
FROM (SELECT id, creation_time  
      FROM thread
      ORDER BY creation_time DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c ON c.thread_id = t.id
WHERE 3 >= (SELECT COUNT(1) 
            FROM comment c2 
            WHERE c.thread_id = c2.thread_id 
            AND c.creation_time <= c2.creation_time
           )
```

I have the first half of the query, but I am struggling with the syntax for the WHERE clause and how to combine it with the JOIN. Any one have any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: First attempt seems to mess up around the .filter() call:

```
c = aliased(Comment)
c2 = aliased(Comment)

subq = db.session.query(Thread.id).filter_by(topic_id=122098).order_by(Thread.creation_time.desc()).limit(2).offset(2).subquery('t')

subq2 = db.session.query(func.count(1).label("count")).filter(c.id==c2.id).subquery('z')

q = db.session.query(subq.c.id, c.id).outerjoin(c, c.thread_id==subq.c.id).filter(3 >= subq2.c.count)
```

this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, comment_1.id AS comment_1_id 
FROM (SELECT count(1) AS count 
FROM comment AS comment_1, comment AS comment_2 
WHERE comment_1.id = comment_2.id) AS z, (SELECT thread.id AS id 
FROM thread 
WHERE thread.topic_id = :topic_id ORDER BY thread.creation_time DESC
 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2) AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN comment AS comment_1 ON comment_1.thread_id = t.id 
WHERE z.count <= 3
```

Notice the sub-query ordering is incorrect, and subq2 somehow is selecting from comment twice. Manually fixing that gives the right results, I am just unsure of how to get SQLAlchemy to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c = db.aliased(Comment, name='c')
c2 = db.aliased(Comment, name='c2')

sq = (db.session
      .query(Thread.id, Thread.creation_time)
      .order_by(Thread.creation_time.desc())
      .limit(5)
      ).subquery(name='t')

sq2 = (
    db.session.query(db.func.count(1))
    .select_from(c2)
    .filter(c.thread_id == c2.thread_id)
    .filter(c.creation_time <= c2.creation_time)
    .correlate(c)
    .as_scalar()
)

q = (db.session
     .query(
         sq.c.id, sq.c.creation_time,
         c.id, c.creation_time,
     )
     .outerjoin(c, c.thread_id == sq.c.id)
     .filter(3 >= sq2)
     )
```

Comment: Thank you van, that does seem to work. Playing around with it, I am able to get the query to return a Comment object; is there a way to get the above query to return actual Model objects, or is that not possible due to the subquery?

Comment: It is possible, of course. In the final query (`q`) you have to query for an object you want, and not for a list of columns. In your case you could query for `Thread` and join it on the `sq` to have the same `id` column value.